# US SMS transactional notification opt-out requirements

Tags: sms, twilio

This is probably on the borderline of being a programming question, but this is really about technology choice at the end of the day.

I am trying to work out what functionality the system should support in the USA, distributing receipt notifications for payments via email and SMS, regarding SMS opt-out. Is it mandatory that for transactional SMSs the user should be able to 'unsubscribe from all communications'? To stress: this is ONLY transactional SMSs (receipts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're considering this because you are building a service using Twilio, then you need not worry about building this functionality. [Twilio handles opt out messages for you](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-).

If you are only delivering transactional SMS messages and think that opt outs should not apply, I encourage you to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to discuss this in more detail.

Comment: Hi philnash...that's really helpful. Any chance you can get hold of a link on the transactional regulations re transactional comms opt-out? The management here seem to think this is a technical problem.

Comment: I genuinely don't have a link for transactional regulations. All I know is that Twilio will handle STOP, etc and opt users out on all numbers that can receive SMS messages except short codes. You do receive the message with the STOP command as a webhook, so you can update your database and potentially send your transactional messages by another means, if that helps at all?

Comment: Man it does, thanks. Problem is we have like 3 different contexts (3 settings in the app for SMS  point of sale receipts, SMS receipt of loyalty awards, SMS of loyalty program updates) all of which are transactional. It looks to me like even if the user sends STOP on these then we'll have to have a separate number for each particular type of message, as they might not want receipts but do want to know if they earned a reward. That kind of thing. But in my opinion....as transactional SMSs..they should be being given the option of managing their settings,and the STOP stuff should be disabled

Comment: I am getting it now.....so if the user sends STOP on say the number that ties to "SMS me if I spend", we can webhook that , update their settings in the db to show it as disabled.....BUT what if the user goes to their account settings and reenables it. How do we cancel the 'STOP' for that user?

Comment: You'd have to add in your settings that to opt back in the user would need to text YES or START to your number, which would take them off the blacklist. You'd get a webhook for that too, so you can update the setting on your side. If you do your best to allow your users to control what you SMS to them through your application, you should find that they use those capabilities rather than the blanket STOP.